# pass argument to view with reverse django

Tags: django, redirect, httpresponse, reverse

I have a view `create_rating` where after I submit a form I want it to be processed on a view `rating_upload` and then i want to redirect back to the `create_rating` view. Cant seem to get it to work, my latest code below. I would think when i click `submit` on the `create-rating` page that it should send `video_id` to `rating_upload`, and from there I can just send it back to `create_rating` as an argument. The docs show this too. I tried several things the latest error is what i have shown..

urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^upload', UploadVideo.as_view(), name='upload'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', VideoView.as_view(), name='videoview'),
    url(r'^(?P<video_id>\d+)/create_rating', create_rating, name='create_rating'),
    url(r'^(?P<video_id>\d+)/rating_upload', rating_upload, name='rating_upload'),
    url(r'^(?P<video_id>\d+)/rating_uploaded', rating_upload, name='rating_upload')
]
```

views:

```
def create_rating(request, video_id):
    vid = get_object_or_404(Video, pk=video_id)
    past_ratings = vid.rating.order_by('date_created')[:5]
    template = loader.get_template('create_rating.html')
    context = {
        'vid': vid, 'past_ratings': past_ratings
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))


def rating_upload(request, video_id):
    template = loader.get_template('rating_upload.html')
    rated_video = Video.objects.get(pk=video_id)
    context = {
        'rated_video': rated_video
    }
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('create_rating', video_id))
```

template, `create_rating.html`:

```
<p>{{ vid.title }}</p>

<form action="{% url 'rating_upload' vid.pk %}"  method="post">

{% csrf_token %}
<input type="text" name="rate_comment">
<input type="submit" value="Rate Video">
```

Latest error:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/video/32/rating_uploaded

Django Version: 1.10.5
Python Version: 2.7.10
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'video']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/Users/RyanHelling/virtualenvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/RyanHelling/virtualenvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/RyanHelling/virtualenvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/RyanHelling/PycharmProjects/flash2/video/views.py" in rating_upload
  63.     return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('create_rating', video_id))

Exception Type: TypeError at /video/32/rating_uploaded
Exception Value: an integer is required
```

Comment: `TypeError at /video/32/rating_uploaded an integer is required` The error feedback seems like its getting the word video and trying to map that to an id when it shouldn't. I don't see /video/ in your routes anywhere so i'm not sure where its getting that from? are you namespacing or importing urls anywhere?

Comment: hi yes I am importing urls to a level above which is `video`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try

```py
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('create_rating', args=(video_id,)))
```

instead of

```py
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('create_rating', video_id))
```

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) suggests passing your args as a tuple.

Comment: i tried that and it is telling me `reverse() takes no keyword arguments`

Comment: @ratrace123, where do you import reverse from? for your error I've found only [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42173580/django-tutorial-typeerror-at-polls-3-vote-reverse-takes-no-keyword-argumen) question and it's about wrong import. According to the docs, reverse takes up to five arguments: reverse(viewname, urlconf=None, args=None, kwargs=None, current_app=None).

Comment: ahhh i think that was part of my problem, i had it importing from audioloop or something like that... i changed it to import from `django.urls`

Comment: ok i think i got it, i changed the import and added `kwargs:  return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('create_rating', kwargs={'video_id':video_id}))`    Thanks!

Comment: args=(video_id) needs a comma at the end args=(video_id,) to make it a valid tuple

Comment: Can we specify to take the 'GET' method in reverse, since I am facing an issue "Method "PUT" not allowed.". I am calling from a PUT method